# How do you constrain the Silverlight Datepicker without a MaxLength property?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I have a Silverlight Datepicker control. I would like to constrain entry to only allow 10 characters. Currently it seems to be unlimited.

There is no maxlength property on the control. Can it be set in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark but did you have a look at the `DatePicker`'s style? I remember having some issues with it and making the text box readonly.

Comment: I had to modify the default style and set the MaxLength property on the internal text box directly via the style. Thanks!